# How to Identify if a ec2 instance is a spot instance or a on demand instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How do identify if a vm is spot instance or a on-demand instance.

I have create a Auto Scaling Group with a mix of On-demand and Spot instance below is the rule configured 
[image]

It did create 4 instances but I am not able to identify which is a spot instance and which are on-demand?

Answer (score 15):

You can do the following:

> In the navigation pane, choose Instances. In the top right corner, choose the Show/Hide icon, and then select Lifecycle. For each instance, Lifecycle is either normal, spot, or scheduled.
>
> Alternatively run this CLI command `aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests \
>       --query "SpotInstanceRequests[*].{ID:InstanceId}"`

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#using-spot-instances-running

Comment: Lifecycle "normal" meaning on-demand?

Comment: @eastwater yes. normal = on-demand, spot=spot.

Comment: I was nervous to see how old this answer was, but I still see a lifecycle value today!

Answer (score 2):

> Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.

> In the navigation pane, choose Instances.

> Select the instance.

> On the Details tab, under Instance details, find Lifecycle. If the value is spot, the instance is a Spot Instance. If the value is normal, the instance is either an On-Demand Instance or a Reserved Instance.

> On the Details tab, under Host and placement group, find Tenancy. If the value is host, the instance is running on a Dedicated Host. If the value is dedicated, the instance is a Dedicated Instance.

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-purchasing-options.html